# How to handle file uploads in a `gatsby js` project?

Tags: gatsby, netlify

There is an excellent [article](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/) explain how to handle form submission in a `Gatsby Js` project hosted on `netlify`. However it's only about text values submission, how about the form includes some file inputs?

Any one can shed some light here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for @coreyward's help. That I figured out the problem here is how to use `javascript fetch API` to post a form data. So the solution here is quite straightforward:

```
const encode = (data) => {
  const formData = new FormData()
  Object.keys(data)
    .map(key => {
      if (key === 'files') {
        for (const file of data[key]) {
          formData.append(key, file, file.name)
        }
      } else {
        formData.append(key, data[key])
      }
    })
  return formData
}

await window.fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: encode({ 'form-name': 'loan', ...this.state, userId: netlifyIdentity.currentUser().id }),
  })
```

You can notice that the only tricky part is rewrite the `encode` function of the [official sample article](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/) from `uri encoding` to `form data encoding`.

Answer (score 2):

Netlify supports file uploads in their form handler without any special configuration: https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/#file-uploads

> Netlify Forms can receive files uploaded via form submissions. To do this, add an input with `type="file"` to any form. When a form is submitted, a link to each uploaded file will be included in the form submission details. These are viewable in the Netlify app, in email notifications, and via our API.

Comment: Yes I knew that. I want a React demo because the official react demo doesn't include a file upload example.

Comment: @JeffTian I'm really unclear as to what you're looking for. React treats `file` inputs as uncontrolled components, but they work normally otherwise. StackOverflow isn't the right place if you're looking to ask Netlify or React to provide a demo on how to use their products.

Comment: thanks for your comments, it made me think how to define the problem and finally solves it by recognizing it's a question of how to use `javascript fetch function` to post form data.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can use [Getform.io](https://getform.io) to setup file upload forms in a Gatsby.js project.

In this [article](https://blog.getform.io/how-to-create-file-upload-forms-on-gatsby-site/) they show an example with Axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from "react"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


const GETFORM_FORM_ENDPOINT = "YOUR-FORM-ENDPOINT";


function Form() {
    const [formStatus, setFormStatus] = useState(false);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
    });

    const handleFileChange = () => (e) => {
        setQuery((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            files: e.target.files[0]
        }));
    };

    const handleChange = () => (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setQuery((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value
        }));
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        Object.entries(query).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            formData.append(key, value);
        });

        axios
            .post(
                GETFORM_FORM_ENDPOINT,
                formData,
                {headers: {Accept: "application/json"}}
            )
            .then(function (response) {
                setFormStatus(true);
                setQuery({
                    name: "",
                    email: "",
                });
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
    return (
        <div class="container-md">
            <h2>Gatsby File Upload Form using Getform.io</h2>
            <form
                acceptCharset="UTF-8"
                method="POST"
                enctype="multipart/form-data"
                id="gatsbyForm"
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
                <div className="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter your email"
                        required
                        name="email"
                        value={query.email}
                        onChange={handleChange()}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter your name"
                        required
                        name="name"
                        value={query.name}
                        onChange={handleChange()}
                    />
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div className="form-group mt-3">
                    <label className="mr-2">Upload your Resume:</label>
                    <input name="file" type="file" onChange={handleFileChange()}/>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                {formStatus ? (
                    <div className="text-success mb-2">
                        Your message has been sent.
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    ""
                )}
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Form
```

PS: They let you submit a single file up to 5MB in their free plan.